# In Netsuite, How do I Change the Max Number of Results That Appear in a Child Record Sublist

Tags: netsuite

I've created a Custom Record that is a child record of a Transaction. On the Transaction when I look at the child record sublist, it shows only 25 results per page. I want to be able to show more results than that.

I've checked the Personal and General Preferences option called "Number of Rows in List Segments," but that doesn't change the number of results that show on the custom child record list. Actually, the default on that preference is 50, so I know it's not related to my child record sublist.

Comment: I don't believe you can. One thing you could try is changing the sublist size in the GUI preferences for the user attached to the token you are executing API requests with (assuming you are using SuiteTalk as opposed to SuiteScript).